# How to save multiple file (.mat) into .wav using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, speech-recognition

I have a .mat file containing 100files. How to convert the 100 files one by one to .wav. 
Every file contain vectors.I tried using this code but I got errors.

```
x=load('data_cropped.mat');
input_list = x;

for i = 1:length(input_list)

                fid = fopen(input_list(i).name);

                data = ' ';

                fopen(fid);


                wavwrite(data,16000,[input_list(i).name(1:length(input_list(i).name)-3),'wav']);

                clear data
```

end

The error is:

```
>> convert_to_wav
Reference to non-existent field 'name'.

Error in convert_to_wav (line 7)
                fid = fopen(input_list(i).name);
```

Please help me,
Thanks a lot

Comment: It seems that there is no field "name". Have you inspected the output of `fieldnames(x(1))`, for example?

Comment: I am sorry, I dont get it..I got the code somewhere from the internet..can u please explain further...I am new and bad in writting codding. thanks Drake

Comment: The code assumes that `x` is a structure array and that each structure in the array has a field named "name". It seems that this is not the case. The command `fieldnames(struct)` returns the names of the fields of a structure `struct`, that's why I suggested it. As a first debugging step. Can you upload somewhere (dropbox?) the code and the .mat file?

Comment: Hi Drake, Thanks for the help. Still downloading the dropbox. I just format the laptop. I cant post the image (screen capture) here. but the .mat file looks like this:<14480X1 double>;<18520x1 double> and so on.Actually what I want to do is, to convert it<14480x1 double> to .wav . but I dont want to do it one by one. How should I do?Thanks

Comment: You will need the sample rate to write .wavs. Is it stored in the file or do you know it?

Comment: @Tobassist, I post the same question at this link http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/124112-how-to-convert-multiple-mat-into-wav, but this time with figure of the .mat file. Please help me, I think it almost get the answer..Thanks a million

Comment: Hi Drake the .mat file is in this link [lik](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lu5r5oran1z2237/data_cropped01.mat)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the sample rate of your audio then the snippet below should do what you want and give you a series of numbered wav files.

```
clear
load('data_cropped.mat');
data = whos;
fs = 44100 %change to your sample rate
for i = 1:length(data)
wavwrite(data(i).name,fs,num2str(i));
end
```

Comment: Hi Tobassist,Thanks for the help, I run the codding and it give me the set of .wav file. However, the file is empty. I think this is because of the sample rate.However, may I know, the sample rate is set the same as the original wav that I cropped ...am I right?Thanks again

Comment: the .wav file produced is not the same counts as the cropped data. What i mean is I supposed to get 17 .wav because I cropped 17 wav signal. However, the cod return 25 data.Is something missing ..thanks

Comment: You need to start from a clear workspace due to the way it creates the variable 'data'. I've edited the code. If that doesn't work I'll need to look at your data file.

Comment: Hi @tobassist, I think there are issues with how I save the result. The result is in cell array. I am not really good in writing coding in Matlab. So please expect some term is not correct.Pardon me.. I think I have to convert the cell to matrix first. I have posted a different question at this forum. Will get back here if the problem solved. Thanks